# Pointers and stacks in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, stack

I am having trouble figuring out how the whole pointer push and pop works. On my program the user is supposed to create a stack which is empty (NULL) and with that the user can select to either push a number on the stack or pop the number which was pushed on, off. Also it is supposed to count the number of stacks and what is stored but I'm assuming i could figure that out if i understand how push and pop is supposed to be written. I understand the concept behind those i just don't know how its supposed to be written. Someone please help me understand this. I went to a tutor but he needed to refresh his memory and told me to come back another day. Which I will, but i cannot rely on that.

Comment: There is no "pointer push and pop" in C++. Also `NULL` doesn't really mean "empty". Can you share you code so that we can help you fix it? I also recommend reading the [tag:stack] wiki page to get a better understanding of what a stack is and how it works.

Comment: It's really hard to help you without knowing what you already know and what you don't For example, do you understand what [std::stack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) is? If not, do you understand containers generally?

Comment: Keep track of the number of stacks or the number of numbers on the stack?

Comment: The [first](http://electrofriends.com/source-codes/software-programs/cpp-programs/cpp-data-structure/c-programs-to-implement-the-stack-adt-using-a-singly-linked-list/) [two](http://vinodcse.wordpress.com/2006/05/25/stack-implementation-using-single-linked-list/) Google results for `"c++ stack implementation using linked list"`. Come back when you've written some code and have a specific problem and we'd be more than happy to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my implementation of `pop`. It should be obvious from this example what would need to be done for `push`. *I can't say this is the most cost efficient way.*

```
template <class T>
T SimpleStack<T>::popOff()
{
    T popped = *(aptr + --arraySize); //aptr points to the existing stack
    int tSize = arraySize;            //arraySize is a member holding the size

    T *temp = new T[tSize];           //Temp holder for the elements that stay 
                                      //on the stack
    for(int i = 0; i < tSize; ++i)
    {
        *(temp+i) = *(aptr+i);        //Fill the temp holder with the original 
                                      //stack - popped
    }
    delete [] aptr;                   //Get rid of the old stack
    aptr = new T [tSize];             //Create a new stack with the new size
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i)
    {
        *(aptr+i) = *(temp+i);        //Fill the new stack with the kept values
    }
    delete [] temp;                   //Get rid of the temp holder
    return popped;                    //Send the popped number back
}
```

The fact still remains that without reading up on what a stack, or any custom container you're trying to emulate, is and how it's used and where it's best suited you'll probably struggle.